# Storing the predictions and coefficients from Stata for n replications

Tags: stata, simulate

I have a following code where I am trying to replicate the estimation for n times and then generating prediction and coefficients for further use.

```
capture program drop mypro
program define mypro
drop _all
sysuse auto
bsample
reg mpg price headroom
mat mycoef=e(b)
gen mypri=mycoef[1,1]
gen myhead=mycoef[1,2]
gen mycons=mycoef[1,3]
predict x1b
end
simulate, seed(10) reps(10) nodots : mypro
```

The `simulate` by default gives only the coefficients from 10 different samples. However, I am trying to save each sample dataset along with coefficients mpri, myhead, myconst,and x1b . Is it possible to do this using `simulate` or do I need to use `loop`?

Updated as per comment of Nick:

```
capture program drop mypro
program define mypro
set seed 1
local r=10
forvalues i=1/`r'{
drop _all
sysuse auto
bsample
reg mpg price headroom
mat mycoef=e(b)
gen mypri=mycoef[1,1]
gen myhead=mycoef[1,3]
predict x1b
save data`i',replace
}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `simulate` to run your program to take a bootstrap sample to get regression results.

```
  sysuse auto
  bootstrap : reg mpg price headroom
```

is a much simpler approach. Look at the documentation for `bootstrap` to learn more.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for not making the question clear. I not only want the coefficients but I also want the prediction (not the summarized) and sampled dataset from each replication.For example, in my case, I want 10 different resampled datasets along with the coefficients,and predictions. These will be used as an input for the further study. The `simulate` and `bootstrap` don't allow me to extract the sampled data (which are used for the analysis internally by the program) for each replication. I tried looking for `postfile` but not sure how to do.

Comment: 10 sounds quite inadequate for any serious simulation work. But I guess you need to loop over `bsample` calls using a `merge` each time. `simulate` is a dead end for you.

Comment: Thank you. Yes,10 is not adequate, but I used here only as a demo. `bsample` doesn't have the options to allow for the looping. Can you please give an extra hint, how to proceed with that?

Comment: I have used the loop as per your suggestion (updated). I want to know whether I need to use the seed inside the loop.

Comment: Setting the seed once is sufficient to ensure repeatability of results.